# What are the advantages and disadvantages of judicial change in law reform?

Tags: england-and-wales, judiciary

There are four ways law can be reformed; either through judicial change, reform by parliament, pressure groups or law reform agencies.

However, what are the advantages and disadvantages of law reform through judicial change in England and Wales?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way law can be *changed* in the U.K.: by statutory instrument, either a bill passed by parliament or a minister (or delegated official) acting under a law that delegates power to them.

Courts can *develop, clarify, interpret, extend or limit* law (and they have to because parliamentary drafting is abysmal) and such decisions are binding on future cases in lower courts.

The others you mention can only *advocate* change.